# Determine all faces of $P$ and their dimensions.

Tags: real-analysis, linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Let $$P = \{x\in\mathbb{R}^4|x_i + x_j \geq 1 \text{ for every pair }i,j\in\{1,2,3,4\} \text{ with } i\neq j\}$$

**Exercise:** Determine all faces of $P$ and their dimensions.

I've never heard of [faces](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Face.html) before, but from what I've read about them they're components of polytopes and polyhedra. In this case $P$ is a polytope, a bounded intersection of a finite set of half-spaces. Since this polytope is four-dimensional, I find it hard to think of what its components might be.

**Question:** How do I solve this exercise?

Comment: Seriously? In geometry, you never talked about the faces of a cube or faces of a tetrahedron? Or in real life, the faces of a die?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks to me like they are using "face" generically, so it would include edges and vertices as well.

$P$ is an object in 4-dimensional space. Faces are extremal subsets of this object that exist in lower dimensional linear subspaces:

- 3-dimensional faces will consist of sets of points where one of the limitations is at its extreme. I.e., there are fixed indices $k,l$ such that $x_k + x_l = 1$, while otherwise the variables take on all values that leave the point in $P$. These will be spacial volumes
- 2-dimensional faces (planar shapes) will be the intersections of two of the 3-dimensional faces.
- 1-dimensional faces (line segments, called edges) will be the intersections of three of the 3-dimensional faces.
- 0-dimensional faces (points, called vertices) will be the intersections of four of the 3-dimensional faces.

Additional intersections will leave you with the empty set.